# How to negate "isblank" function, with full row conditional formatting

Tags: google-sheets

BACKGROUND: I am editing a google forms response sheet. I would like new rows to be red, until they are assigned a status. I have already used the data validation tool to create a list of statuses, and assign color to the entire row using conditional formatting.

I decided the easiest way to do this is to use the timestamp column (L).
something like: IF L=NOTBLANK then COLOR=RED

I've seen another post in which the user asked how to negate the "isblank" function in google sheets. The solution to his question was

`=not(isblank(A1))`

I tried to use this + my own conditional formatting to color an entire row red, if the L cell in that row was not blank.

My formula looks like this

`=$A2=not(isblank(l2))`

HOWEVER, this turns everything but the first row red.

What would be the correct syntax? Here's a pic of my current results
[image: Here's a pic of my current results]

Comment: Can you please simplify/clarify to explicitly state what exactly you're trying to achieve? You want the row highlighted if the value in L is blank?

Answer (score 0):

> I would like **new rows to be red, until they are assigned a status**.

Please use the following

```
=isblank($L2)
```

> I tried to use ... **to color an entire row red, if the L cell in that row was not blank**.

Please use the following

```
=not(isblank($L2))
```